# Files copied to hard drive via USB adapter disappear when booting from the drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, usb-storage

I had a large amount of data on one laptop (`A`) that needed to be moved to another laptop (`B`). Both laptops are running Windows 10 x64.

I removed the SATA hard drive from Laptop `B` and connected it to Laptop `A` via Unitek USB 3.0 to SATA adapter.

I created a folder on the root called `X:\TEMP`.  Then I copied all the data (80 GB) to this folder via Windows Explorer.  I then verified that the files were there. Then…

- I set the permissions of this folder to "Everyone: Full Control" and ensured that permissions would propagate to the subfolders and files.
- I unmounted the drive (Safely Removed) via Windows taskbar.
- I reinstalled the drive in Laptop "B" and booted from it into Windows 10.

The `C:\TEMP` folder is gone! I would expect something to happen with permissions, where I would have to take ownership before I could see it, but in this case it was simply NOT THERE.

I scanned the drive with my file recovery utility, and there's no trace of the directory. I ran `chkdsk /f` to make sure the file allocation table was not corrupted.  Still nothing.  Not even a `FOUND.000` folder.

I did this twice and still nothing. What on Earth is going on here?!?

Answer (score 2):

This might have to do with how Windows 8 and later accelerate booting by not actually shutting down when you tell them to, but instead going into "hibernate mode". This leads to them keeping the MFT in memory (which gets saved into the pagefile), instead of reading it from the actual physical copy on the disk. It is however only that copy that gets updated by a different operating system while the main OS is offline, which in turn means the main OS will not see the updates made.

You can relatively easily shut down your system once cleanly by following these steps:

1. Shift+Click on the "Reboot" button in the start menu.
2. In the screen that appears, select "Reboot into Firmware Interface".
3. When there, press the power button once to switch the Laptop off. (If that doesn't work, hold the power button for a few seconds.)

Note that this will inevitably lead to a longer loading time the next time you boot up Laptop B, which might be very noticeable depending on the actual hardware.

Comment: That's a great answer. I saw someone else commenting  that disabling fast boot would fix this type of issue but I didn't connect it to a cached MFT. Thx for clarifying the "why".